# Snow leopard wiki server question

Tags: wiki, apple, osx-snow-leopard

I wonder if it is possible to enable some kind om wiki markup language (like in an ordinary wiki) to edit the wiki pages on apple wiki server 2? Are users forced to use html or the visual editor or are there any other options?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visual editor will only manage a limited set of HTML tags. You can however extend the functionality using CSS, XSL or JavaScript. For more information, see the Apple documentation for extending Wiki Server (a must to read for every admin):

http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/Extending_Your_Wiki_Server.pdf